# Does Meteor createContainer re-compute when the injected params change?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a Meteor/React application and am using the Meteor `createContainer` container method to collect data from Mongo and pass the results into a child component. I am finding that when any of the `params` change, the Mongo query re-computes (even though the params do not affect the Mongo query itself) and the props are sent onto the child component which causes it to re-render unecessarily. Is this the way `createContainer` is supposed to work, or should it simply just send down props only when the data that is returned by the query changes?

```
export default MyComponentContainer = createContainer(( params ) => {

    // Some Mongo queries...
    var query results = MyColl.find({}).fetch();

    return {
        query results  
    };

}, MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will re-compute and its wrapped component will re-render when `params` change, because the `params` will be passed down to `MyComponent`, and React will re-render `MyComponent` because its props have changed.

If your `results` is a big array and you do not want to re-render `results`, I suggest you use another child component inside `MyComponent` to render `results`:

```
const ResultComponent = (props) => props.results.map(...);

const MyComponent = (props) => ({
  <div>
    <ResultComponent results={props.results} />
  </div>
});
```

This way `ResultComponent` will only re-render when `results` changes

Comment: To add to that, you can also use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to prevent `MyComponent` from re-rendeeing if it's not needed.

Comment: Generally speaking, in React, if one out of five props changes, does this cause all the locations within this component, where the five props are used, to update their values?

Comment: If your component does not have child component, everything inside it will be re-render when one of props changes.

Comment: Would you say that this is counter-intuitive to the way that you would expect React to behave, i.e. for it to know that a prop hasn't changed therefore not to update it, or the entire component for that matter?